# How to allow ContinuousAction on something that is not all

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, gui-construction

I have this code:

```
DynamicModule[{r = 1},
Grid[{{Slider[Dynamic[r]], SpanFromLeft},
{f[Dynamic[r]], g[Dynamic[r]]}}]]
```

While I move the slider, $f$ ang $g$ are evaluated continually, but only $f$ should be. I want $g$ to be evaluated only with the final value of $r$. (When I release left click)

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ControlActive](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlActive.html) is useful for this purpose:

```
DynamicModule[{r = 1, old = 1}
, Grid[
    { {Slider[Dynamic[r]], SpanFromLeft}
    , {Dynamic[f[r]], Dynamic[g[ControlActive[r, old = r]; old]]}
    }
  ]
]
```

The variable `old` has been introduced to hold the "old" value of `r`.  The key expression is `ControlActive[r, old = r]; old`, which always returns the value of `old`.  However, it also checks to see if there is a control actively updating `r`.  If not, `old` is assigned the final value of `r`.

**DynamicWrapper**

The expression`g[ControlActive[...];old]` is a bit obscure.  It mixes two concerns: the display of `g[old]`, and the synchronization logic between the slider and the variable `old`.  It would be nice if we could separate these concerns, especially if `old` were referenced for display in multiple places.

Version 8 introduced [DynamicWrapper](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicWrapper.html) for this purpose.  It allows us to separate out the synchronization logic:

```
DynamicModule[{r = 1, old = 1}
, DynamicWrapper[
    Grid[
      { {Slider[Dynamic[r]], SpanFromLeft}
      , {Dynamic[f[r]], Dynamic[g[old]], Dynamic[h[old]]}
      }
    ]
  , ControlActive[r, old = r]
  ]
]
```

The display expressions `Dynamic[g[old]]` and `Dynamic[h[old]]` are now nice and clean.  The sychronization logic has been moved to the second argument of `DynamicWrapper`.  That logic will be active as long as the wrapped element, `Grid[...]`, is visible.

Answer (score 10):

`Dynamic` has this build into it. You can take advantage of the Dynamic second and third arguments. The second argument of evaluate as the dynamic is being updated. The third argument is evaluated when the mouse is released. Which is what you want.

To illustrate, here is an example, where `f[r]` and `g[r]` are inside the arguments of the slider itself. This is where you would actually do the call from. But to see the effect, I put the values of their calls in the last entry of the grid. It shows, with a time stamp, that only the `f[r]` is called while the mouse is moving, and `g[r]` is only called when the mouse is released.

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{r = 1, fv = 0, gv = 0},

 g[z_] := Column[{"g called ", z, Date[]}];
 f[z_] := Column[{"f called ", z, Date[]}];

 Grid[{
   {

    Slider[Dynamic[r,
      {(r = #) &, 
       (r = #; fv = f[r]) &,  (*called as the slider moves*)
       (r = #; gv = g[r]) &   (*called only when the mouse is released*)
       }]
     ], SpanFromLeft},

   {Dynamic@fv, Dynamic@gv} (*to see the effect only. Needed for display*)

   }, Frame -> All
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Not much to add to the code below. Indeed, it seems `EventHandler` is a solution to your problem. You need `PassEventsDown` to let the slider update.

```
DynamicModule[{r = 1, s = 1},
 EventHandler[
  Grid[
   {
    {Slider[Dynamic[r]], SpanFromLeft},
    {Dynamic[f[r]], Dynamic[g[s]]}
    }
   ],
  {"MouseUp" :> (s = r)}, PassEventsDown -> True
  ]
 ]
```